# set в class поменять bool переменную

Tags: c++

в дебагере показывает что все работает и меняет, но когда я вывожу на принт оно не меняеться

```
class Theater
{
/...
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Ticket>> tickets;
}

std::vector<std::vector<Ticket>> Theater::getVector()
{
    return tickets;
}

class Ticket
{
/...
private:
    int row{};
    int seat{};
    double price{};
    bool occupied{};
}
bool Ticket::getOccupied()
{
    return occupied;
}

void Ticket::setOccupied(bool occupied)
{
    this->occupied = occupied;
}
```

и в main хочу поменять значение с true на false для occupied

```
if (th.getVector()[row][seat].getOccupied() == true)
            th.getVector()[row][seat].setOccupied(false);
```

но ничего не происходит ...

Answer (score 1):

У Вас функция

```
std::vector<std::vector<Ticket>> Theater::getVector()
{
   return tickets;
}
```

возвращает **копию** вектора векторов.

Поэтому, когда Вы делаете вот так

```
th.getVector()[row][seat].setOccupied(false);
```

Вы на самом деле создаете временную копию, в ней меняете и потом эта копия удаляется...

Что делать? возвращать ссылку!

```
std::vector<std::vector<Ticket>>& Theater::getVector()
{
   return tickets;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, глупая ошибка

Comment: но я бы сделал отдельно функцию виде `setOccupied(int row, int col, bool occupied)` ну и геттер похожий. и не показывать наружу внутренности.